# Cannot enter drive D via command prompt

Tags: path, command-prompt, disk

I cannot enter my other disk partition using command prompt, it says "The device is not ready" every time i tried to access it. I can enter drive C but, not D. I have granted all privileges of disk D upon users, authenticated users, administrator and system. I also ran the command prompt as administrator but it gave the same result. Any solution ? Thank you so much for all of your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below links might help you, Please check it

https://superuser.com/questions/776669/command-prompt-error

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bf8038a6-0d7c-4ecd-b2e7-7b2e2cc4826f/using-command-prompt-to-change-from-c-to-e-the-device-is-not-ready?forum=w8itprogeneral